# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'SearchFieldListItem<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart, search

```dart
Widget airportList() {
  return Container(
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Airports").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.data == null){
          return Container();
        } else {
          List<SearchFieldListItem<String>> airportDetail = [];
          for(int i=0;i<snapshot.data!.docs.length;i++){
            DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
            airportDetail.add(data["Airport Name"]);
          }
          return Form(
            key: _airportKey,
            child: SearchField(
              hint: "Enter airport Name",
              itemHeight: 50,
              maxSuggestionsInViewPort: 6,
              suggestionsDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
              onTap: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedAirport = value as String;
                });
              },
              suggestions: airportDetail,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried for 2 days I could not find the answer

Answer (score 0):

**your Code Demo**

```
Widget airportList() {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Airports").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container();
          } else {
            List<SearchFieldListItem> airportDetail = []; // here is the list type u define is SearchFieldListItem..
            for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
              DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
              airportDetail.add(data["Airport Name"]); // here you put a String inside a list of SearchFieldListItem that is not applicable otherview convert the datatype or chnga the add property
            }
            return Form(
              key: _airportKey,
              child: SearchField(
                hint: "Enter airport Name",
                itemHeight: 50,
                maxSuggestionsInViewPort: 6,
                suggestionsDecoration:
                    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                onTap: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedAirport = value as String;
                  });
                },
                suggestions: airportDetail,
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

**change code here**

```
List<String> airportDetail = []; 
airportDetail.add(data["Airport Name"].toString());
```

Comment: Its not working the same error accores

Comment: try to print the date["Airport Name"].. then you willl be ure what type of list you get and waht type of list you have.

Comment: I didn't use this package, but maybe you should create a SearchFieldListItem before adding it to the list? Something like this: `airportDetail.add(SearchFieldListItem(data["Airport Name"]));`